Add text before book title in ASCIIDoc?
New to ASCIIDocs--wondering if there is an easy way to add text (a single centered word) before the book title.
I've successfully entered text before the title (0-level) however it appears to mess with downstream formatting.

AsciiDoc, which is originally intended as a text-based way to construct structured documents in accordance with the DocBook XML specification, has no provision for any text appearing before the book title. (Nor, for that matter, can I imagine how any book structure could accommodate such a thing.) If that doesn't suit you, perhaps AsciiDoc is not the tool you're looking for.
